# Do I have to collect my checked luggage when transiting through Sao Paulo?

Tags: transit, luggage, check-in, brazil, united-airlines

Im looking to fly from Newark to Brazil on United airlines and then Brazil to Argentina on an Brazilian airline called Gol. Im worried that I may have to collect my bags in Brazil and then check them in with Gol...all of this in a one hour time period (layover time). Is this something that I have to do or will United make the transition for me since I booked the flight ticket all the way to Argentina and not on separate tickets?

Comment: As São Paulo is your entry point in Brazil, you will need to get your bags and check them it again.

Comment: @MarcelP. This is only correct if she has another flight within Brazil.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have an international connection in Brazil (e.g. Newark-Sao Paulo-Buenos Aires), you do not need to fetch your bags or go through immigration.

If you have a connecting flight within Brazil (e.g. Newark-Sao Paulo-Rio de Janeiro-Buenos Aires), you **do** need to fetch your bags, go through immigration & customs, and check your bags again.